# ListSelectionListener Action is Fired, but JDialog Displayed After 2nd Click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jdialog, miglayout

I want to open a JDialog (CustomerUpdateDialog) after clicking a JTable (part of a JDialog called: CustomerListDialog) row only once, however it takes two clicks to open CustomerUpdateDialog.

Here is the code for the JTable:

```
public class CustomerListDialog extends JDialog {

private void initComponents(ArrayList<Customer> customers) {

    ...

    ListSelectionListener listener = new ListSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");

                Date date = format.parse (tbl_Settings.getValueAt(tbl_Settings.getSelectedRow(), 8).toString());
                LocalDate joinDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

                Customer customer = new Customer.Builder(Validator.Id(tbl_Settings.getValueAt(tbl_Settings.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString()),
                        tbl_Settings.getValueAt(tbl_Settings.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString(),
                        tbl_Settings.getValueAt(tbl_Settings.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString(),
                        tbl_Settings.getValueAt(tbl_Settings.getSelectedRow(), 6).toString()) //
                                .streetName(tbl_Settings.getValueAt(tbl_Settings.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString()) //
                                .city(tbl_Settings.getValueAt(tbl_Settings.getSelectedRow(), 4).toString()) //
                                .postalCode(tbl_Settings.getValueAt(tbl_Settings.getSelectedRow(), 5).toString()) //
                                .emailAddress(Validator.Email(tbl_Settings.getValueAt(tbl_Settings.getSelectedRow(), 7).toString()))
                                .joinDate(joinDate)//
                                .build();

                System.out.println(customer.toString());
                System.out.println(e.toString());

                CustomerUpdateDialog customerUpdateDialog = new CustomerUpdateDialog(customer);
                customerUpdateDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(CustomerUpdateDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                customerUpdateDialog.setVisible(true);

            }
            catch (ApplicationException | ParseException e1) {
                System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
            }

        }
    };

    tbl_Settings.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(listener);
}

private JTable createTable(ArrayList<Customer> customers) {

    String[] columnNames = "Customer ID,First Name,Last Name,Street Name,City,Postal Code,Phone Number,Email Address,Join Date".split(",");

    int rows = customers.size();
    int cols = columnNames.length;
    String[][] data = new String[rows][cols];

    for(Customer customer : customers) {
        int i = customers.indexOf(customer);
        for(int j=0; j<cols; j++) {
            String cellData = null;
            switch (j) {
                case 0:
                    cellData = String.valueOf(customer.getId());
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cellData = customer.getFirstName();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cellData = customer.getLastName();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cellData = customer.getStreetName();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    cellData = customer.getCity();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    cellData = customer.getPostalCode();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    cellData = customer.getPhoneNumber();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    cellData = customer.getEmailAddress();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    cellData = customer.getJoinDateString();
            }
         data[i][j] = cellData;
         } 
    }

    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

    return table;
}

public CustomerListDialog(ArrayList<Customer> customers) {
    setBounds(100, 100, 1000, 500);
    initComponents(customers);
}

}
```

and here is the code where I add the JTable dialog to the main menu:

```
JMenuItem mntmCustomersList = new JMenuItem("List");
    mnCustomers.add(mntmCustomersList);
    mntmCustomersList.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    mntmCustomersList.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    mntmCustomersList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CustomerListDialog dialog = new CustomerListDialog(customerList);
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

A sample list of customer data:

```
Customer [id=1739, firstName=Kaitlin, lastName=Oneil, streetName=P.O. Box 329, 9608 Tortor Road, city=Diegem, postalCode=64447, phoneNumber=834-890-3976, emailAddress=enim.sit.amet@sedlibero.edu, joinDate=2014-04-12]
Customer [id=2210, firstName=Octavius, lastName=Joseph, streetName=Ap #342-9819 Quis St., city=San Leucio del Sannio, postalCode=55477-429, phoneNumber=671-872-7563, emailAddress=nisi.sem@orcilobortis.ca, joinDate=2018-06-18]
```

Why do I need to click a row twice in order to open another dialog?

Thank you.

*** UPDATE ***

I've changed the MouseListener event handler to ListSelectionListener as per @AndrewThompson's comment and @Lunatic0's answer, but I'm still getting the same result.

I find that I click the table, then I can click any other application on my computer, and then the dialog will be displayed.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the table. For ease of use, use only J2SE core layouts. 2) Prefer composition to inheritance. In this case that means using standard dialogs, rather than custom ones. 3) For a `JTable`, use the more specialized `ListSelectionListener` rather than a mouse listener.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson, I tried using ListSelectionListener, but I still get the same result. Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test this snippet and adapt to your custom dialog situation.

Basically, you just need to create the listener and then set it to your table by using
`getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(listener)`

Also, put the table inside a `JFrame` instead of a `JDialog`, I don't know for sure why but seems to only work properly with the `JFrame`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class TableExample {
    JFrame f;

    TableExample() {
        f = new JFrame();

        String data[][] = { { "101", "Amit", "670000" }, { "102", "Jai", "780000" }, { "101", "Sachin", "700000" } };
        String column[] = { "ID", "NAME", "SALARY" };
        JTable jt = new JTable(data, column);
        jt.setBounds(30, 40, 200, 300);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jt);
        f.add(sp);
        f.setSize(300, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);

        ListSelectionListener listener = new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hello");
                System.out.println(jt.getValueAt(jt.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());

            }
        };

        jt.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(listener);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TableExample();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to try to put that `JFrame` inside a `JDialog`, didn't tested it but might do the trick if you really need to use a dialog.